# Ember mixins - is this a good way to achieve 'dynamic' layout

Tags: javascript, ember.js, architecture, mixins

What I'm trying to achieve:

The app has a few "main sections", such as top panel, sidebar, and of course content. I would like to have a per-route 'configuration' which of those are shown (content is always present), with most routes having same, default, layout.

My solution:

- Application template binds each section's visibility to relevant ApplicationController property
- I have a LayoutMixin which, upon entering the route, gets the route's layoutSettings property, and updates the ApplicationController properties accordingly
- When leaving the route, mixin reverts back the previous state

Minimalistic example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fidoquhira/2/edit?html,css,js,output

The approach works, and I quite like the concept of using mixin + 'config data' to make things happen 'automagically' (I'm also doing a similar thing for breadcrumbs), but am kinda worried I'm reducing clarity of what is going on, or that I'm not seeing something that may blow up at some later point.

Is this "the Ember way" of doing things?

Additionally: how to write unit tests for such mixin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your problem primarily deals with what information is displayed at any given point rather than business logic, my solution would be to bind the visibility of your top panel and sidebar views to properties in the application controller. If you were to use a mixin, I would use one that alias the properties in the application route and maybe gives you some actions for showing, hiding, or toggling state. For example:

```
//application controller
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    isTopPanelVisible: false,
    isSideBarVisible: false
});

//panel visibility mixin
export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    needs: ["application"],
    isTopPanelVisible: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.application.isTopPanelVisible"),
    isSideBarVisible: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.application.isSideBarVisible"),
    actions: {
        showTopPanel: function(){
            this.set("isTopPanelVisible", true);
        },
        showSideBar: function(){
            this.set("isSideBarVisible", true);
        }
    }
});

//controller for some route
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend(panelVisibility, {
    initializeRoutesVisibility: function(){
        this.set("isTopPanelVisible", true);
        this.set("isSideBarVisible", false);
    }.on("init")
});

//sidebar view
export default Ember.View.extend({
    classNameBindings: ["hidden"],
    hidden: true,
    setVisibility: function(){
        if (this.get("controller.isSideBarVisible"){
            this.set("hidden", false);
        } else {
            this.set("hidden", true);
        }
    }.observes("controller.isSideBarVisible").on("didInsertElement")
});

//top panel view
export default Ember.View.extend({
    classNameBindings: ["hidden"],
    hidden: true,
    setVisibility: function(){
        if (this.get("controller.isTopPanelVisible"){
            this.set("hidden", false);
        } else {
            this.set("hidden", true);
        }
    }.observes("controller.isTopPanelVisible").on("didInsertElement")
});

//some css file
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

I think this solution is more "Ember" and gives you a lot more flexibility. State is stored in one place that everything else observes, business logic goes in the controllers, display logic goes in views.